# How to determine one year from now in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get one year from now's date, and it's not working.

JS:

```
var now = new Date();

var oneYr = new Date();
oneYr.setYear(now.getYear() + 1);
$("#yearFromNow").append(oneYr.toString());

var oneMonth = new Date();
oneMonth.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1);
$("#monthFromNow").append(oneMonth.toString());
```

Output:

```
one mo. = Thu Dec 22 112 15:16:01 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

one yr. = Sun Jan 22 2012 15:16:01 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

The year has `Dec 22 112` - ??  The month is correctly displaying `Jan 22 2012`.

If you want to tinker with it, http://jsbin.com/alezaj/edit#javascript,html,live.  This is in Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You should use `getFullYear()` instead of `getYear()`. `getYear()` returns the actual year minus 1900 (and so is fairly useless).

Thus a date marking exactly one year from the present moment would be:

```
var oneYearFromNow = new Date();
oneYearFromNow.setFullYear(oneYearFromNow.getFullYear() + 1);
```

Note that the date will be adjusted if you do that on February 29.

Similarly, you can get a date that's a month from now via `getMonth()` and `setMonth()`. You don't have to worry about "rolling over" from the current year into the next year if you do it in December; the date will be adjusted automatically. Same goes for day-of-month via `getDate()` and `setDate()`.

Comment: For anyone wondering how it deals with leap years, I did this in a Firefox console ... >> x = new Date('2000-02-29') 
-> Date 2000-02-29T00:00:00.000Z
>> x.setYear(2001)
-> 983404800000
>> x.toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y')
-> "01-Mar-2001"

Comment: Isn't this hilarious? To get a date one year from now in javascript one needs to write:

`new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1))`

Answer (score 293):

This will create a `Date` exactly one year in the future with just one line. First we get the `fullYear` from a `new Date`, increment it, set that as the year of a `new Date`. You might think we'd be done there, but if we stopped it would return a timestamp, not a `Date` object so we wrap the whole thing in a `Date` constructor.

```
new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1))
```

Comment: `setYear()` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear), `setFullYear()` should be used instead.

Comment: One liner with no intermediate variables to allocate!  Excellent!

Comment: this will not handle the hours, mins and seconds, it will be set to current time

Comment: If you call this exactly at the end/begin of the year, different calls of new Date() can return different years, increasing by (almost) two years or none!?

Comment: maybe not the most efficient

Answer (score 42):

As `setYear()` is deprecated, correct variant is:

```
// plus 1 year
new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)
// plus 1 month
new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 1)
// plus 1 day
new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)
```

All examples return Unix timestamp, if you want to get `Date` object - just wrap it with another `new Date(...)`

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
var startDate = new Date();
    startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() - 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

Using some of the answers on this page and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13838662/312089), 
I came up with my own answer as none of these answers fully solved it for me.

Here is crux of it

```
var startDate = "27 Apr 2017";
var numOfYears = 1;
var expireDate = new Date(startDate);
expireDate.setFullYear(expireDate.getFullYear() + numOfYears);
expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() -1);
```

And here a a JSFiddle that has a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wavesailor/g9a6qqq5/

Comment: whats the expireDate.getDate() - 1 for?

Answer (score 2):

Use setFullyear as others have posted but be aware this returns a timestamp value not a date object. It is also a good candidate imho to add functionality via the prototype. This leads us to the following pattern:

```
Date.prototype.addYears = function(n) {
    var now = new Date();
    return new Date(now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + n));
};

console.log('Year from now is', new Date().addYears(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

In very simple way. use this code.

```
// define function 
function nextYearDate(date1) {
    var date2 = new Date(date1);
    var date3 = date2.setDate(date2.getDate() - 1);
    var date = new Date(date3);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    var year = date.getFullYear()+1;
    var newdate = year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
    $("#next_date").val(newdate);
}
// call function.
<input type="date" name="current_date" id="current_date" value="" onblur="nextYearDate(this.value);" />

<input type="date" name="next_date" id="next_date" value="" onblur="nextYearDate(this.value);" />
```

Comment: Why on earth is JQuery rearing its ugly head here? JQuery != JS