# Today's day minus number of days

Tags: javascript

How can I display today's date with minus 5 days in below format?

Today's date:    `18/03/2016`

Last sync date:  `13/03/2016`

I have tried the with below example though I am able to achieve today's date, not before 5 days date...

PS: I have tried with **alert(todayDate) - 5** without luck :(

Any help please?

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var todayDate = ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' +  ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear();
alert(todayDate);
```

I'm using jQuery if that's relevant.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. It's a JavaScript question.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838441/javascript-how-to-calculate-the-date-that-is-2-days-ago    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Got the answer... `var todayDate = ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '' - 5) + day + '/' +  ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear();`