# Adding years to a date string?

Tags: javascript

How can I add years to a date String in JavaScript?

Example:

`var date = "01/01/1983"`

I would like to add 26 to "1983". The result should be this "01/01/2009" String.

Could this be done with a replace() method instead of new Date()?

Comment: is your date mm/dd/yyyy format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add year to todays date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070428/add-year-to-todays-date)

Comment: @Leogoesger: Quetion specifically mention no new Date()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by providing a function to `.replace`:

```js
const input = "01/01/1983";
const output = input.replace(/\d+$/, year => Number(year) + 26);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var parts ='01/01/1983'.split('/');
var mydate = new Date(parseInt(parts[2]) + 1, parts[1] - 1, parts[0]); 
console.log(mydate.toDateString())
```

Comment: Thank you, but the output of your code  is Sun Jan 01 1984 (timestamp) which I can't utilize. I require "01/01/2009" as a String.