# Find day of week of any year, plusYears() function Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, date

I've done a bit of searching and either haven't found an example that fits, or perhaps I just can't quite grasp some of concepts yet.

I'm trying to write a function that lets the user input a date (from a form) and return every year where the date falls on a Friday over the next 50 years. I'm sure there are several things wrong with my initial approach, but **my primary concern is the .plusYears() function is not working.** Thanks for any feedback!

```
<script>
function date() {
  var weekday = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var date = new Date(input).getUTCDate();
  console.log("date: " + date);
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    date = date.plusYears(i);
    console.log("date: " + date);
    if(date.getDay() == 6){
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = date.getDate() + ", " + weekday[date];
    }
  }
}
</script>

<form>
  <input type="date" placeholder="dd:mm:yy" id="input" />
  <input type="button" value="weekday" onclick="date()" />
</form>
  <p id="output"></p>
```

EDIT:

```
function date() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var date = new Date(input);
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var y = 1;
    date = new Date(date.getFullYear() + y, date.getMonth(), date.getDate()); 
    if(date.getDay() == 5){
      console.log("friday" + date);
    }
    else{
      console.log("other day");
    }
  } 
}
```

Unsure why the console is displaying the date prior to whichever the user inputs.

Comment: What do you expect `.plusYears()` to do? Where does that come from? And note that `.getUTCDate()` returns a number; a day-of-month value specifically.

Comment: When using date-only strings, it's likely that *getUTCDate* will return a different date to the local date where the host is set for a timezone west of Greenwich. Also, 29 Feb 2016 plus 1 year will be 1 March 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `plusYears` isn't a function on [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#). I use the method recommended in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070428/add-year-to-todays-date) to construct a new date (`date = new Date(date.getFullYear() + i, date.getMonth(), date.getDate())`). Also, Friday is day 5 (not day 6). See inline comments below:

```html
<script>
  function date() {
    var weekday = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var date = new Date(input);
    console.log("date: " + date);
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      date = new Date(date.getFullYear() + i, date.getMonth(), date.getDate()); // construct new date like this
      console.log("date: " + date);
      if (date.getDay() == 5) { // Friday is 5 (not 6)
        // use date.getDay() to get the correct index of the day name in your week array.
        // Also, append this new value so that it doesn't overwrite the other.
        // You may want to add formatting etc.
        document.getElementById('output').append(document.createTextNode(date + ", " + weekday[date.getDay()]));   
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<form>
  <input type="date" placeholder="dd:mm:yy" id="input" />
  <input type="button" value="weekday" onclick="date()" />
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

plusYear()? where did you get this function from?

try something like

```
date.setFullYear(date.getFullyear() + i);
```

should work.

Comment: Well it should probably only get the year once, or else always add 1.

Comment: Right, so `i` goes from 0 to 50. Each time through the loop the year value from the previous iteration is increased by `i`, so it'd go 2018, 2019, 2021, 2024, 2028, etc.