# How can I add 3 years to a date using Google scripting?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add 3 years to a date that I have extracted from a cell on a Google sheet.  My coded currently looks like this:

```
var courseDate = values[row][col];

var courseDay = courseDate.getMonth();
var courseMonth = courseDate.getMonth();
var courseYear = courseDate.getYear();

var renewalDate = new Date(courseYear + 3, courseMonth, courseDay);
```

Comment: [Check out the **MDN** documentation for Javascript's **Date** class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). The methods/functions you need are documented in that link.

Comment: You have taken `getMonth()` instead of `getDate()` in courseDay calculation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add year to todays date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070428/add-year-to-todays-date)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  This now works - a combination of using getDate() and correcting my error using getMonth() twice.

var courseDate = values[row][col];
      
var courseDay = courseDate.getDate();
var courseMonth = courseDate.getMonth();
var courseYear = courseDate.getFullYear();

var renewalDate = new Date(courseYear + 3, courseMonth, courseDay);

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var c = new Date(year + 3, month, day)
```