# How to get record if createdDate is from one year later using sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

How to get record if createdDate is from one year later using sequelize

```
userId createdDate
1.      2023-07-19 00:49:59
2.      2022-08-20 00:49:59
```

Tried

```
 return this.findAll({
       createdDate: {
        [Op.gte]: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 1)
       }
    });
```

```
Expected Record
2.      2022-08-20 00:49:59
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

// Assuming your model is named 'YourModel'
const YourModel = require('./path/to/your/model');

// Get the current date
const currentDate = new Date();

// Calculate the date exactly one year ago from the current date
const oneYearAgo = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() - 1, currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate(), currentDate.getHours(), currentDate.getMinutes(), currentDate.getSeconds());

// Perform the query
return YourModel.findAll({
  where: {
    createdDate: {
      [Op.gte]: oneYearAgo,
      [Op.lt]: currentDate,
    },
  },
});
```

You calculate the `oneYearAgo` date by subtracting one year from the current date's year and keeping the same month, day, hours, minutes, and seconds. Then, we use the `Op.gte` operator to find records greater than or equal to oneYearAgo, and the `Op.lt` operator to find records less than `currentDate`. This way, we retrieve records with a `createdDate` falling within the last one year.

#### EDIT based on question:

should subtract 1 year from the current date.

```
// Get the current date
const currentDate = new Date();

// Calculate the date exactly one year ago from the current date
const oneYearAgo = new Date(currentDate);
oneYearAgo.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() - 1);

console.log(oneYearAgo);
```

Comment: thanks for for helping, if want to get createdDate that is 1 year less from today `expected record: 2023-07-19 00:49:59` then i should add 1?

Comment: check edit! i answered you question there

Answer (score 0):

from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33070496/15557206

you can get date + 1 full year with:

```
const aYearFromNow = new Date();
aYearFromNow.setFullYear(aYearFromNow.getFullYear() + 1);
console.log(aYearFromNow);
```