# Find user defined year back dates without using library

Tags: javascript

I want to get dates 2 years prior to today in JavaScript not using any library.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but exchanging `+` with `-` should not be a problem: [How to determine one year from now in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609261/how-to-determine-one-year-from-now-in-javascript)

Comment: This does not seem to be a quality question. Shows lack of research.

Comment: And regarding the comment `[...]I want all the days in between them.[...]`: [Javascript - get array of dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413590/javascript-get-array-of-dates-between-2-dates)

Comment: Nearly all Date related questions have already been asked and answered multiple times on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you guys know then please provide me the guidance not provide other already have questions and all.

Comment: @Ms.KV I did. The answers in the first link provides the way to get the date two years back. And the second link has a function to get all dates between those two dates. So what else do you need. In the current from the question does not contain a problem that has not been already answered here, so it is a duplicate. If you think those answers won't work with your problem, then explain why.

Comment: Thanks for your time @t.niese, Suppose  let say 18 yrs. is minimum than it should display date 18yrs prior to today or  default date can be todays date.This is i am working on and need help.

Comment: @Ms.KV this still does not explain what part of your problem is not covered by those two answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `date.getFullYear()` on the `Date()` object, to get the current year and subtract that by `2`

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setFullYear( date.getFullYear() - 2 );
console.log(date);
```

Comment: I want all the days in between them.

Comment: @Ms.KV you didnt specify that in the question

Comment: @mast3rd3mon- Yes i did not mentioned.But i edited the question.